# Where is the recurrent neural network in the preprocessing layer of the "A Compare-Aggregate Model for Matching Text Sequences" model?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

I read on the "[A Compare-Aggregate Model for Matching Text Sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01747)" model that the "preprocessing layer uses a recurrent neural network":

> Our **preprocessing layer uses a recurrent neural network to process the two sequences**.
>   We use a modified version of LSTM/GRU in which we keep only the input gates for remembering meaningful words:
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> \nonumber
> \overline{\mathbf{Q}} & = & \sigma(\mathbf{W}^\text{i} \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{b}^{\text{i}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_Q) \odot \tanh(\mathbf{W}^{\text{u}}\mathbf{Q}+\mathbf{b}^{\text{u}}\otimes \mathbf{e}_Q), \\
> \overline{\mathbf{A}} & = & \sigma(\mathbf{W}^\text{i} \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{b}^{\text{i}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_A) \odot \tanh(\mathbf{W}^{\text{u}}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{b}^{\text{u}}\otimes \mathbf{e}_A),
> \end{eqnarray}
>   where $\odot$ is element-wise multiplication, and $\mathbf{W}^\text{i}, \mathbf{W}^\text{u}\in \mathbb{R}^{l\times d}$ and $\mathbf{b}^\text{i},\mathbf{b}^\text{u}\in \mathbb{R}^{l}$ are parameters to be learned.
>   The outer product $(\cdot \otimes \mathbf{e}_X)$ produces a matrix or row vector by repeating the vector or scalar on the left for $X$ times.
>
> The attention layer is built on top of the resulting $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ and $\overline{\mathbf{A}}$ as follows:
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> \nonumber
> \mathbf{G} & = & \text{softmax} \left(   ( \mathbf{W}^{\text{g}} \overline{\mathbf{Q}}  + \mathbf{b}^{\text{g}} \otimes \mathbf{e}_Q)^{\text{T}} \overline{\mathbf{A}} \right), \\
> \label{eqn:alpha}
> \mathbf{H} & = & \overline{\mathbf{Q}} \mathbf{G},
> \end{eqnarray}
>   where $\mathbf{W}^{\text{g}} \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times l}$ and $\mathbf{b}^{\text{g}} \in \mathbb{R}^{l}$ are parameters to be learned, $\mathbf{G}\in \mathbb{R}^{Q\times A}$ is the attention weight matrix, and $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times A}$ are the attention-weighted vectors. 
>   Specifically, $\mathbf{h}_j$, which is the $j^\text{th}$ column vector of $\mathbf{H}$, is a weighted sum of the column vectors of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ and represents the part of $\mathbf{Q}$ that best matches the $j^\text{th}$ word in $\mathbf{A}$.
>   Next we will combine $\mathbf{h}_j$ and $\overline{\mathbf{a}}_j$ using a comparison function.
>   % Here, each column of $\mathbf{H}$ can be treated as the word representation in $\mathbf{Q}$ that is more likely to be aligned with the corresponding column in $\mathbf{H}^\text{a}$. Next, we will make use of these aligned information and build the matched representation between them.

Where is the recurrent neural network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [comment](https://openreview.net/forum?id=HJTzHtqee&noteId=ByZAYNRbg) from the review process has the same concern. The authors posted a revision of the paper [here](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HJTzHtqee) which clarifies the matter: The equations shown for $\overline Q$ and $\overline A$ are not a recurrent network. However, on one of the experimental tasks, they did use an LSTM to compute $\overline Q$ and $\overline A$ instead of using their proposed equation.